# How to create sub-issue use jira soap

Tags: soap, jira

in the JiraSoapService class ,i can't find any method to create a sub issue or link to another issue.
mine jira Rpc plugin version is 4.2.1-b588.

any one help me!

thinks.

Answer (score 2):

According to JIRA feature request [JRA-6896](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-6896), this was added to JIRA 4.4 with SOAP call [createIssueWithParent](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#createIssueWithParent%28java.lang.String,%20com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteIssue,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JIRA SOAP is with limited functionallity, just for some data retrival, and for some issue generation, don't hope for something more specific.

AFAIK, sub-issue is same issue as others, it just has specific type as others do (ask with [getIssueTypes](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/service/IssueConstantsService.html#getIssueTypes%28com.opensymphony.user.User%29)), when creating issue, set that type of your sub-task issue.